# Cannot connect to SQL Azure using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

I have create a SQL Azure database on the Azure portal, now I want to connect to it using SQL Server Management Studio. I've set my properties like this:

```
Server Type:Database Engine:
Server Name:[mycred].database.windows.net
Authentification: SQL Server Authentification
username: myusername
password: mypassword
```

But when I try to connecting with these properties I get an error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

Whereas I have configure firewall on my SQL Azure database. How to solve this issue?

Comment: which version of SSMS are you using?  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657348/cannot-connect-to-sql-server-client-side-issue)

Comment: Are you sure you're still appearing to Azure as the same IP address you've configured the firewall for? This can change if your DHCP lease has been renewed by your provider, the service has gone down, you've rebooted your cable modem or router, you've connected to a VPN, etc. etc.

Comment: i'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio version 10.0.1600.22,

Comment: My ip address still same which i configure on firewall, I have configure my local firewall which allow inbound and outbound port 1433  Any other suggesstions  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your request has not left your machine that's why it is returning network error. There could be several issues and first start with SQL Server Management Studio. You must have SSMS R2 2008. Any non R2 version will not work.

Here is a list of test you would need to perform to troubleshoot the problem and apply solution:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/sql-azure-connectivity-troubleshooting-guide.aspx

Comment: My my is SQL Server 2008 Management STudio, is it not R2 2008 too, in about page, it's show version 10.0.1600.22. is my mine right ?

Comment: I dont remember the version but I am dead sure that only SSMS 2008 R2 connects with SQL Azure and you must have it to connect with SQL Azure.

Comment: OK, i get some strange when troubleshoot my connection problem.I can't "telnet <myserver>.database.windows.net 1433" console say that couldnot open connection to host. Where as i have allow 1433 port on my compute firewall, i have allowed this port on both of inbound and outbound connection, any suggesstions?

Comment: Hi AvkashChauhan, i'm sorry i don't know how useful of this.OK begin now i will give rate for answer which help me :)

Comment: Any idea how to make sure that i can access 1433 port, because on my firewall i have allow that port both of inbound and outhbound port.I'm also have tried to disable my firewall, but still same.I can't access it

Comment: I just don't feel happy helping you further... it is discouraging that you don't give credit to others for their hard work to help you..