# Unable to connect to Azure database from SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

When i am trying to connect to the Azure DB from SQL Management studio an getting teh below error. Not sure why am getting this error as i was able to acess the DB erlier from SQL Management Studio. 
Need help on this.

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to ijk3ffy48i.database.windows.net.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Comment: What if your DB instance used up all account money and is no longer available?

Answer (score 1):

Simple things to check (not sure what you've tried so humour me here):

- You're connected to the outside network.
- Instance\Database name, username and password are correct.
- Instance and database are online and connectable (Azure servers not down for scheduled maintenance or run out of paid services.)
- Firewall rules are incorrect.

Also I think this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827307/cannot-connect-to-sql-azure-using-sql-server-management-studio) is identical to your question. Try checking that out.

Answer (score 1):

I think probably you haven't configure any Azure DB firewall rules to allow your computer's IP to communicate with your Azure DBs.

Comment: This is probably what is happening.